# Chrome Headless: Get DOM of only visible nodes

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom, google-chrome-headless

I've been looking for a way for Chrome Headless to output only the visible 
DOM nodes as a tree.

I'm using the code below to output the entire DOM, but this includes invisible elements.

```
Runtime.evaluate({expression: 'document.documentElement.outerHTML'})
```

Is there a way to prune all the invisible nodes?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about doing this as a tree. For that, I think you'd have to get all the nodes and then walk the tree and remove non-visible ones yourself.

This will return a node list.

```
Runtime.evaluate({expression: 'document.querySelectorAll("*:visible")'})
```

Comment: Interesting. Do you think I could select all hidden elements using "*:hidden" and remove each of them?

Comment: Well, you would actually search for `document.querySelectorAll("*:not(:visible)")` and then you could remove them.

Comment: Perfect. I'll give it a shot now.

Comment: Typing `document.querySelectorAll("*:visible");` into Chrome's console gives me a `'*:visible' is not a valid selector.` error. What's the issue?

Comment: @Brad Sorry. My bad. You can do this, but you'll need JQuery for `:visible` to work.

Comment: No worries, I'll look into some alternatives.